# Use the Cauchy theorem to check whether a function is analytic or not in some region

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

Let $f $ be complex value defined  in some bounded closed  region $\gamma $ (rectangle) but we don't know whether it has poles or not in $\gamma$.

Let us consider the integral $I$ given by

$$I=\int_{\gamma} f(z)dz $$

Now we have two cases:

1. If $I=c$ where $c \in \mathbb{C}$ and $c$ different from $0$ so in this case, we deduce that $f$ is not analytic in the region $\gamma$ because if it is analytic the Cauchy theorem says that $I$ should be zero but we find it different from $0$.
2. Now the second case when $I=0 $, in this case, we can't say that $f$ is analytic or not in $\gamma$ (because there are some functions which are not analytic but they integral is zero).

So the Cauchy theorem works in one direction if $I$ is different from $0$ then $f$ it is not analytic in $\gamma$.

My question is what is the condition that makes the Cauchy theorem work in the other direction that means

If $I=0$ $\Longrightarrow$ $f$ is analytic and has no poles in $\gamma$

I suggest the condition for  any
$$z_{0} \in \gamma \hspace{0.2cm}\& \hspace{0.2cm} \lim\limits_{z \to z_0} \frac{1}{(k-1)!} \left( \frac{d^{k-1}}{dz^{k-1}} (z-z_{0})^{k}f(z) \right) \neq  0 $$

Because the residue theorem tells us that $I=\sum \text{res} (f;z_{0})$

Is this condition is enough to say that theorem work in the other direction?

Comment: If we strengthen the condition to be that the integral over *any* closed curve is zero, then we basically get [Morera's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem). If the contour is fixed, then really, since we only know that $f$ is integrable on $\gamma$, it could pretty much be arbitrary everywhere else. Based on what you've suggested in your question, it seems reasonable that you might want to assume that $f$ is at least meromorphic...

Comment: You mean $z_0$ is in the interior of $\gamma$? Even assuming you know $f$ is meromorphic, how are you checking to eliminate *all* possible orders $\ge 2$ of pole at all possible points in the interior of $\gamma$?

Comment: I put a suggestion I am not sure if it is work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. This won't work. Consider $\displaystyle\int_\gamma \bar z{}^2\,dz$ with $\gamma$ the unit circle.

Comment: You mean my suggestion or the implications on the direction can't be happen

Comment: You said the function was complex-valued, not even meromorphic. So you can allow functions that are perfectly smooth everywhere inside $\gamma$ and still cannot detect analyticity.

Comment: What do you mean by smooth ?

Comment: Infinitely differentiable.

Comment: What about the condition do you have any idea

Comment: No, the best I can do is Morera's Theorem  (which assumes continuous functions). There's no way to rule out (higher-order) poles other than to assume the function is bounded, but as my example shows, knowing the integral on one curve only won't do it